# Unity Moving Platform script stops working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a script that should move a platform between 2 positions.
The platform moves to pos1 but then just stops....

Here is my code : 
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pos1, pos2;

    public float speed;

    public Transform startPos;

    Vector3 nextPos;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        nextPos = pos1.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (transform.position == pos1.position)
        {
            nextPos = pos2.position;
        }
        if (transform.position == pos2.position)
        {
            nextPos = pos1.position;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(pos1.position, pos2.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting it sequentially, so it's always going to be the second option.

In one case if `nextpos` is in `position 1`, it'll be set to position 2, but is then immediately changed again as 
if `nextpos` is in `position 2`, it'll be set back to 1.

easy change should be just to change the second `if` statement to an `else if`

paraphrasing the code, but hopefully it makes sense

Comment: Also It's better to use Vector3 class for holding positions instead of Transform class.